# Pyspark JSON object or file to RDD

Tags: python, json, pyspark, rdd

I am new to PySpark and I have an AskReddit json file which I got from [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit.json). I am trying to create an RDD which I then hope to perform operation such as map and flatmap. I was advised to get the json in a jsonlines format but despite using pip to install jsonlines, I am unable to import the package in the PySpark notebook. Below is what I have tried for reading in the json.

```
In [10]: import json

         data = json.load(open("AskReddit.json", "r"))
         jsonrdd = sc.parallelize(data)
         jsonrdd.take(5) 

Out[11]: [u'kind', u'data']
```

I also tried to do the following which gives me the whole contents of the json file after doing jsonrdd.take(1).

```
In [6]: jsonrdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("*.json")
        jsonrdd.take(1)
```

However, I would like to get each json object as one line in the rdd. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use SparkSQL's `read.json` to read the file like -

```
jdf = spark.read.json("path/to/AskReddit.json")
```

and perform all kind of sql type of operation, even rdd type of operations on it.But json struture is really really nested with no fixed columns that can be derived with something like `explode`

[image: Json Structure]
You are better off with using `read.json` and using dataframe like-

```
jdf\
.withColumn('after',jdf.data.after)\
.withColumn('before',jdf.data.before)\
.withColumn('modhash',jdf.data.modhash)\
.withColumn('NestedKind',explode(jdf.data.children.kind))\
.withColumn('subreddit',explode(jdf.data.children.data.subreddit))\
.withColumn('clicked',explode(jdf.data.children.data.clicked))\
.show()

+--------------------+-------+---------+------+--------------------+----------+---------+-------+
|                data|   kind|    after|before|             modhash|NestedKind|subreddit|clicked|
+--------------------+-------+---------+------+--------------------+----------+---------+-------+
|[t3_66qv3r,null,W...|Listing|t3_66qv3r|  null|3r7ao0m7qiadae13d...|        t3|AskReddit|  false|
|[t3_66qv3r,null,W...|Listing|t3_66qv3r|  null|3r7ao0m7qiadae13d...|        t3|AskReddit|  false|
```

Comment: Is there any way I can store each row as a line such as in jsonLines format?

Comment: what is the spark object ? could you show your import statement ?

Comment: `import pyspark.sql.* `

Answer (score 3):

Use SparkContext library and read file as text and then map it to json.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local","task").getOrCreate()
rddfile = sc.textFile(filename).map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using spark 2.0+ you can do the following:

```
df = spark.read.json(filename).rdd
```

Check out the documentation for [`pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=read#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json) for more details. Note this method expects a JSON lines format or a new-lines delimited JSON as I believe you mention you have.

Comment: Actually I need to get it in JSON lines format. I used pip install jsonlines. However, when I try to import the package in the jupyter notebook running spark it says no module found even though I can import when running python in the terminal.